# Subprocess kills parent process instantly

Tags: python, subprocess, mkdocs

When I try to run `mkdocs serve` as a subprocess and use CTRL+C to quit the MkDocs server, the parent Python process quits instantly, too. Not even finally clauses or functions registered with `atexit` are called.

```
try:
  os.system('mkdocs serve')
finally:
  print('>> finally')
```

What the heck is going on? I can't find anything suspicious after looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/master/mkdocs/commands/serve.py#L53-L92) of the `mkdocs serve` command. Tested with Python 3.4 on Windows.

---

Update: Turns out this seems to be an issue with Mintty (GitForWindows) on Windows.
Everything works fine if I run the Python script from Cmder or the native Windows command prompt..

Comment: Mm, does the same happen if you run `cat`, or another program? Is the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception reaching your script?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the `KeyboardInterrupt`, if it was I would be able to catch it and the finally-clause should be executed. It works fine with `cat`. :)

Comment: Wait, I'm confused, I could swear it just worked. :') Apparently it doesn't work with `cat`... So maybe it is a keyboard interrupt that is not raised as a KeyboardInterrupt exception by Python?

Comment: @slezica Just added an update to the question, it appears to be an issue with Mintty.